# Proving that $ f: (a,b) \to \Bbb{R}; ~ x \mapsto (b - a) \left( \frac{1}{a - x} + \frac{1}{b - x} \right) $ is bijective.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I want to prove that every open interval in $ \Bbb{R} $ has the same cardinality as $ \Bbb{R} $.

I first defined a function $ f: \Bbb{R} \setminus \{ a,b \} \to \Bbb{R} $ by
$$
\forall x \in (a,b): \quad
f(x) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=}
(b - a) \left( \frac{1}{a - x} + \frac{1}{b - x} \right).
$$
The problem is that I could not prove that $ f $ is **bijective** on $ (a,b) $ (I know that $ f $ is not bijective on either $ (- \infty,a) $ or $ (b,\infty) $).

I could not prove that $ f $ is surjective. I know that the formal definition of surjectivity is: ‘$ f: A \to B $ is surjective if for all $ b \in B $, there exists an $ a \in A $ such that $ f(a) = b $’, but I do not know how to use this.

Any ideas?

Comment: you wrote $f$ is not bijective for $x<a$ but i am wondering since function is not defined their

Comment: Show that $f(x)\to +\infty$ as $x\to b$ and $f(x)\to -\infty$ as $x\to a$. The continuity of $f$ (something you may have to show) will then give the surjectivity.

Comment: If you need help for injectivity, you can differentiate and get that $f$ is strictly increasing on $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f: (a,b) \to (0,1)$ as $f(x)= \frac {x-a}{b-a}$ which is easy to see bijective.  Next define $g: (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ as $g(x)=\tan(\pi{x}-\frac{\pi}{2})$ which is also bijective. Since composition of two bijective map is again bijective. Hence $g\circ f :(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$  give the required bijection between $(a,b)$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The problem is that I am not allowed to use trigonometric functions

Comment: @AlexTurner,fine let me think other way.